# How do I solve `mod_rewrite` not being available when installing Symphony CMS?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, symphony-cms

I keep getting this error in the browser

```
Symphony Error: mod_rewrite is not enabled
It appears the mod_rewrite is not enabled or available on this server.
```

I use WampServer, have extracted the Symphony CMS zip to `wamp/www` and followed the install procedure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Left-click the WampServer icon in your system tray
2. Select ‘Apache’ > ‘httpd.conf’
3. Remove the `#` before `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and save the text file
4. Restart Apache by left-clicking the WampServer icon and selecting ‘Restart All Services’